# Spring: Helper Class replacement

Tags: spring

I'm new to Spring.

Back in the not so long ago days.

I have a Helper Class with static methods help to assemble and build objects.

But i realize I can't @Autowired static variables.

May I know what is spring replacement for helper class with static method? Or I should make them into @Service classes too?

Comment: Why do you want to autowire beans to static fields?

Comment: because the helper class static method needs to access it.

Comment: Yes, you can simply annotate them with `@Component` or `@Service`, and thus make them injectable singleton Spring beans.

Answer (score 8):

You can use @Component annotated classes. It is the base of all other components. Your class would be something like :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("assembler") // giving name to component is not mandatory, could be @Component
public class Assembler {

    public boolean assemble(Object obj) {
        // your stuff here
    }
}
```

This is your assembler component. You can use this in other classes using :

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private Assembler assembler;

    @RequestMappings(//mappings done here)
    public String showMsg() {
        // here you use assembler component
        boolean response = assembler.assemble(new Object());
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

This is just an example. I hope you get my point.

Comment: hmm what is the benefit of annotating it as a @Component =x

Comment: While writing a utility or helper class, it is preferred to create Component class instead of making it a Service. If you don't want to mark the class with @Component, you can declare the class as a bean directly in your XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two different approaches that can help you to solve this issue.

**Issue: calling service function or repository function from a helperClass with static method gives an error of type *NullPointerException*: Cannot invoke**.

**Note:** the injection method is **@Autowired**.

```
@Autowired
private static WelcomeService welcome;
```

**solution 1:**

Use constructor injector:

```
    private static WelcomeService welcome;

@Autowired
private WelcomeUtility(WelcomeService welcomeService) {
    WelcomeUtility.welcome = welcomeService;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Using @PostConstruct to set the value to Static Field

```
private static WelcomeService welcome;

@Autowired
private WelcomeService welcomeService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.welcome = welcomeService;
}
```

Source: [source of the solution](https://codezup.com/autowired-with-static-method-in-spring-spring-boot/)